# To combine a word in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

```
Dim a // consider a variable as
a= Ajay Kumar Holla

and i would like to have a output as "AjayKumarHolla"

1) I would like to remove the space and join the word together.
```

2) the code is in VB Script and I would like to have my answer also in VBScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? `a = Replace(a, " ", "")`

Comment: not like this I would like to join words together without space. output should be "AjayKumarHolla" see here I don't have any space.

Comment: My example outputs it with no spaces.  I'm not sure I understand your question then.

Comment: consider this example: I have a value as "Management & Support" but i want my output as "Management&Support".

Comment: You're welcome.  Please accept the answer if it was what you were looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69225/discussion-between-ajay-kumar-holla-and-roryap).

Comment: is it possible even to remove "&" and write some other character? in that code it self?

Comment: Sure, just use `Replace(a, "& ", "others")` instead.

Comment: ya i tried but now its showing "Management Support" again space in between?

Comment: I got the answer it should be "Replace(element.Name, " & ", "")" . space & again space then replace value.